# Does adding breakpoint in a matlab m file make it run slower?

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab m file that basically has two sections

The first section contains a large loop that does operations on arrays of size 64, with the loop itself running about 2000 times

After this loop is finished, the second section contains code that isn't much computationally expensive

I need to invoke a breakpoint ( I do this by clicking on the left margin on the editor window) after the first section finishes, but whenever I set a breakpoint the first section of the program takes significantly longer to execute

I am not changing anything in the program itself. The breakpoint is never in the first section. The program runs really fast when there is no breakpoint (less than 10 seconds) as opposed to when I set a breakpoint after the first section (about 60 seconds)

Is this expected behaviour? Why is having a breakpoint causing the program to run slower? Is there a way to fix this?

MATLAB Version 7.9.0.529 (R2009b) 64 bit on Windows 10 64 bit Home edition

Comment: You could try breaking your code into two separate functions, there is a chance MATLAB will optimise the function which doesn't contain the breakpoint - this is pure speculation

Comment: @Wolfie I ended up dividing the two parts into two files. I run the first part in one file and then run the seconds file immediately. I just had to make sure the second file didn't have any variables with the same name as the first file

Comment: If you made them functions (instead of scripts) and properly structured your code you could call the 2nd one from the first and the variables wouldn't shadow each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Does adding breakpoint in a matlab m file make it run slower?": Yes.

In all languages*, debugging mode is slower because it requires extra power to be able to stop the code, and disables most of the optimization that the interpreter/compiler does.

Nothing really you can do against it (well, not debug, but that defeats the purpose hehe).

[*]: I know about